# In Python, how can I prohibit class inheritance?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Final classes in Python 3.x- something Guido isn't telling me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825364/final-classes-in-python-3-x-something-guido-isnt-telling-me)

I was watching a talk ([How to design a good API and why it matters](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw)) in which it was said, literally, "*design and document for inheritance, else prohibit it*". The talk was using Java as an example, where there's the '**final**' keyword for prohibiting subclassing. Is it possible to prohibit subclassing in Python? If yes, it'd be great to see an example...
Thanks.

Comment: Now I just *have to* post this link I just read when asking a related question a few minutes ago: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2010/07/wikileaks-to-leak-5000-open-source-java.html

Comment: Okay, so you *can*. But you *shouldn't*, lest you violate all idioms and anger all Python users.

Comment: @delnan - I was just wondering whether I can do it at all.

Comment: It is possible with https://github.com/wemake-services/final-class

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no Python keyword for this - it is not Pythonic.

Whether a class can be subclassed is determined by a flag called [Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE) which can be set via the C API.

> This bit is set when the type can be used as the base type of another type. If this bit is clear, the type cannot be subtyped (similar to a “final” class in Java).

You can however emulate the behaviour using only Python code if you wish:

```
class Final(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, classdict):
        for b in bases:
            if isinstance(b, Final):
                raise TypeError("type '{0}' is not an acceptable base type".format(b.__name__))
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict(classdict))

class C(metaclass=Final): pass

class D(C): pass
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825364/final-classes-in-python-3-x-something-guido-isnt-telling-me/2826746#2826746)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I was asking for. Also, I was searching for similar questions, but wasn't able to find anything, so I posted the question.

Comment: I don't know in which version of Python you can use the syntax for class C but I had to change for version 2.5 as:

class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = Final

To make it work.

Comment: i wish people would stop using "it is not Pythonic" as an excuse for things that just haven't been implemented yet. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0591/#the-final-decorator

Comment: @PierreThibault: The OP's answer is Python 3 metaclass syntax, yours is Python 2.

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, classes should generally not have any subclassing restrictions at all. I would like to suggest the third option: Add a comment in your class' documentation that states that the class is not meant to be subclassed.

Comment: This is the best way. "We're all consenting adults here"