# Python: variable in the main program passing into the sub function

Tags: python

Python rookie question, in the following code,how does batch_size passing into sub function eval_on_data ? Is it global variable?

```
epochs = 10 
batch_size = 128

def eval_on_data(X, y, sess):
    total_acc = 0
    total_loss = 0
    for offset in range(0, X.shape[0], batch_size):
        end = offset + batch_size
        X_batch = X[offset:end]
        y_batch = y[offset:end]

       loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy_op], feed_dict={features: X_batch, labels: y_batch})
        total_loss += (loss * X_batch.shape[0])
        total_acc += (acc * X_batch.shape[0])

   return total_loss/X.shape[0], total_acc/X.shape[0]

   ...

   val_loss, val_acc = eval_on_data(X_val, y_val, sess)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly
>   global. If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the
>   function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared
>   as global.

From: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html

Comment: I feel this quote is misleading as the context here seems to be specific to toplevel functions. The more pertinent quote from the documentation is this one: "When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the _nearest_
enclosing scope.  The set of all such scopes visible to a code block
is called the block's *environment*. If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block.  If a name is bound at the
module level, it is a global variable. If a variable is used in a code
block but not defined there, it is a *free variable*."

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following code snippet as an explanation:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

def fun1():
  a = 4
  def fun2():
    b = 5
    print a,b,c

  fun2()
```

```
>>> fun1()
4 5 3
>>> print a,b,c
1 2 3
```

When you define a function, it 'inherits' variables from the calling scope.
Obviously, once you redefine that variable locally within a function, then the local definition applies for the remainder<sup>1</sup> of the function.

This is why `fun1` inherits `b` and `c`, defined at "top level" (i.e. `fun1`'s enclosing scope), which it then passes on further to the 'nested' function `fun2`.

`fun2` (whose enclosing scope is `fun1`) then inherits `a` as defined within `fun1`, as well as `b` and `c`, since this was inherited by `fun1`.

Specifically, note that `a` inside `fun2` is `4`, not the global `1` (as another answer here seemed to suggest).

When you only have one function defined at top level, you could conceptually perceive that as being 'nested' at the top level, and therefore inherits the variables defined at top level (i.e. effectively global scope, even if not explicitly defined as such via the global keyword).

Have a look at `help("NAMESPACES")` for more details

---

<sup>1.To be clear, I don't mean that you can use the inherited value for a while and suddenly define a local version half-way through; if you do this python will complain that you tried to "use a local variable before assignment". I just mean that you either use the inherited version, or explicitly redefine it, which effectively makes it a local variable of the same name for use in that function.</sup>

Comment: Example of fun 2 is great! thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Pythons global variable access is not as strictly enforced as in other languages. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423668/8375919). 
Similarly, python's encapsulation is unlike other languages, too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216917/8375919) or [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641236/8375919)

Comment: Except Python _does_ have class encapsulation, just not specified class access control. Which is a different matter entirely from global variable access.