# python inherent from 'final' class

Tags: python, regex, cpython

In python - a final class is a class that other classes can't inherit from because of [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114382/10577976)(for example - bool class should always have only 2 instances - true or false).

However - in my case, I want to inherit from re.Match (the regex Match class). the thing is that this class is written in c and apparently the [`Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949004/10577976) flag is not enabled in the c-python implementation of this class.

if i would try:

```py
class Region(re.Match):  # Error: type 're.Match' is not an acceptable base type
   ...
```

I'm not sure why this flag isn't enabled in this case but it could be great if I could at least try and not be restricted by a flag.

there is a pythonic way to prohibit inheritance([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3949004/10577976)) but is there a python way to allow inheritence?

I can try to solve it by [enabling this flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825423/10577976) in the c implementation but I want to avoid it.

I can also try rerefer each needed method and attribute by hand to inner match:re.Match variable(want to avoid this also).

I'm looking for a more 'Pythonic' solution.
any ideas?

Comment: Even if you could inherit from `re.Match`, you couldn't `__init__` one by hand anyway: `re.Match()` says "cannot create 're.Match' instances". So how would you imagine getting your hands on an instance of a `Region` like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use a simple proxy object á la

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, match: re.Match):
        self.__dict__["match"] = match  # hoop jumped due to __setattr__

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return getattr(self.match, key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        raise NotImplementedError("Regions are read-only")
```

Comment: Methods just work since they're bound methods in Python. `region.group` gets you the 
`group` method already bound to the inner `match`.

Comment: this already done but at still a workaround