# Cannot subclass mlpy.LibSvm in Python

Tags: python, libsvm

I want to subclass the LibSvm object class exported from the mlpy machine learning package:

```
from mlpy import MaximumLikelihoodC, LibSvm 

class Svm(LibSvm):   

def __init__(self,Gs,ls):
    self._K = ls.shape[1]
    self._Gs = Gs
    self._N = Gs.shape[1]
    self._ls = ls
    LibSvm.__init__('c_svc','rbf',\
            gamma=1.0/self._N,C=100,probability=True)
```

When I call the constructor, e.g.,

```
svm = Svm(Gs,ls)
```

the interpreter ignores my **init** and executers the **init** method of LibSvm, giving an error

```
svm = SVM(Gs,ls)  
File "libsvm.pyx", line 146, in mlpy.libsvm.LibSvm.__cinit__ mlpy/libsvm/libsvm.c:1803)
ValueError: invalid svm_type
```

I have no problem subclassing MaximumLikelihoodC using the same syntax.

Comment: That should have been LibSvm.__init__(self,'c_svc','rbf',\
            gamma=1.0/self._N,C=100,probability=True), but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python classes that are implemented in C cannot be subclassed unless they are specially designed for it, see [Which classes cannot be subclassed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed).

By the looks of the error message, it seems pretty certain its implemented in C, and I expect the author didn't put in the extra work to make it subclassable.