# i am trying to derive from 'buffer' class in 2.6 but unable to do so

Tags: python, python-2.6

```
class memoryview(buffer):
    def tobytes(self):
        return self

buf = memoryview('23')
buf.tobytes()
```

python interpreter gives me the following error

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'buffer' is not an acceptable base type
```

Why it is so

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the question linked in the comments for the list of possible reasons behind dissallowing this.

The direct *technical* reason has to do with how Python classes are declared in C. The interesting part is right at the bottom of [`bufferobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/38fcb9a63398/Objects/bufferobject.c#l839):

```
PyTypeObject PyBuffer_Type = {
    ...
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GETCHARBUFFER | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_NEWBUFFER, /* tp_flags */
    ...
};
```

This field, `tp_flags`, includes a potential setting called [`Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE), which isn't used here. If it *was*, like it is in, for example, [`listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/38fcb9a63398/Objects/listobject.c#l2785), inheriting from `buffer` would be allowed.