# python, is function an object?

Tags: python, function, oop, python-2.7

Given the following behaviour:

```py
    def a():
       pass


    type(a)
    >> function
```

If type of `a` is `function`, what is `type` of `function`?

```py
    type(function)
    >> NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

And why does `type` of `type` from `a` is `type`?

```py
    type(type(a))
    >> type
```

Lastly: if `a` is an `object`, why it cannot be inherited?

```py
    isinstance(a, object)
    >> True

    class x(a):
       pass
    TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
        function() argument 1 must be code, not str
```

Comment: All of those seem correct. What do you expect `type(function)` to return?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are "first class" objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of any function is `<type 'function'>`. The type of the type of function is `<type 'type'>`, like you got with `type(type(a))`. The reason `type(function)` doesn't work is because `type(function)` is trying to get the type of an undeclared variable called `function`, not the type of an actual function (i.e. `function` is not a keyword).

You are getting the metaclass error during your class definition because `a` is of type `function` and you [can't subclass functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed).

Plenty of good info [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html).

Answer (score 3):

The type of `function` is `type`, which is the base metaclass in Python. A metaclass is the class of a class. You can use `type` also as a function to tell you the type of the object, but this is an historical artifact.

The `types` module gives you direct references to most built in types.

```
>>> import types
>>> def a():
...    pass
>>> isinstance(a, types.FunctionType)
True
>>> type(a) is types.FunctionType
```

In principle, you may even instantiate the class `types.FunctionType` directly and create a function dynamically, although I can't imagine a real situation where it's reasonable to do that:

```
>>> import types
>>> a = types.FunctionType(compile('print "Hello World!"', '', 'exec'), {}, 'a')
>>> a
<function a at 0x01FCD630>
>>> a()
Hello World!
>>>
```

You can't subclass a function, that's why your last snippet fails, but you can't subclass `types.FunctionType` anyway.

Comment: Why do I get the error `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` if I do `a = types.FunctionType(compile('return 0', '', 'exec'), {}, 'a')` work? Also, note that in Python 3, your second example should be `a = types.FunctionType(compile('print("Hello World!")', '', 'exec'), {"print": print}, 'a')`.