# Is there a way to subclass a generator in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, subclassing

Aside from the obvious, I thought I'd try this, just in case:

```
def somegen(input=None):
    ...
    yield
    ...

gentype = type(somegen())
class subgen(gentype):
    def best_function_ever():
        ...
```

Alas, Python's response was quite hostile:

```
"TypeError: Type generator is not an acceptable base type"
```

As luck would have it, that's a problem for me. See, I was thinking that maybe it *would* be a fun base type to play with, if I gave it a chance. Imagine my surprise! ..and dismay. Is there no way to get the almighty Python to see things my way on this one?

This is most certainly an outside-the-box kinda question, so please don't just say that it's not possible if you can't think of a way immediately. Python (especially Py3) is very flexible.

Of course, if you have evidence of why it *cannot* (not "should not") be a base type (Py3), then I *do* want to see and understand that.

Comment: A `generator` is a type of `method`.  A `class` can only inherit from other `class`'s.  It would be analogous to building a car out of driving.  I can understand the frustration because I am of the opinion that python should be able to do anything and everything, but I do see why they wouldn't take the time to implement it.

Comment: @FarmerJoe I'm not sure that I get the analogy, but a `method` is essentially (maybe even actually) a subtype of `function`. Also, everything is a type, even type itself ;)

Comment: @FarmerJoe  What I mean by that is that, under the covers, everything is a `class`, even `generator`. Somewhere deep in the internals, one would surely find some C equivalent of `class generator(function)` and it's that class that I'm looking to "subclass" (ie: I am perfectly happy doing something else that allows me similar flexibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot subclass a generator that is defined as a function using `yield`, but you can use it in another generator.

Just take this simple one :

```
def alphagen(n=27):
    if n<0 or n > 27: n = 27
    for i in range(n):
        yield chr(ord('A') + i)
```

You get :

```
>>>> [ a for a in alphagen(10)]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
```

You can use it in:

```
def alphastartgen(n=27):
    resul = ""
    for i in alphagen(n):
        resul += i
        yield resul
```

And now you get :

```
>>> [ a for a in alphastartgen(8) ]
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'ABCDE', 'ABCDEF', 'ABCDEFG', 'ABCDEFGH']
```

Comment: That's a fascinating angle.. I'm gonna go play with it for a while. I'll be back. Thanks

Comment: I'm back from playing with that a bit, and I've gotta say: "Oh ya. That's the good stuff". Treating the outer generator (function) definition like a class definition is exactly the kind of crazy hack I was hoping for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

A relevant other question is [Which classes cannot be subclassed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed).

It's reason 2 in the accepted answer there -- subclassing of a type needs to be implemented in C, and it wasn't implemented for generators, probably because nobody saw a use case.

The source code for generator objects is [genobject.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/genobject.c?view=markup), and you can see on line 349 that the Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE flag is not set.

Comment: Ooo. That's nice. Is that the only thing preventing my from subclassing a gen? Are there other parts of the internals that would need to be convinced? Can this be done at runtime (monkeypatch?) or am I could to need to make a custom build? (a long road I'm trying to avoid for the moment lol)

Comment: Also.. how did you find that flag? Like, you just knew about it, or you followed the code there or something?

Comment: I Googled and found the previous Stack Overflow thread that I linked to, and read it... And the flag isn't enough, you also have to _implement_ how it would work (see, say, the code for list), and recompile Python.

Comment: Or actually it was another question like it I guess, I found a few and saw the flag in one of them.

Comment: Even though I'm accepting the other answer, I want you to know that I found this answer useful. Thank you.