# How do I extend, mimic, or emulate the range function?

Tags: python

I made a little generator function for character ranges:

```
>>> def crange(start, end):
...     for i in range(ord(start), ord(end)+1):
...             yield chr(i)
...
```

And then I can do this:

```
>>> print(*crange('a','e'))
a b c d e
```

Yay! But this doesn't work:

```
>>> crange('a','e')[::2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

And this works, but is O(n), unlike `range`'s O(1):

```
>>> 'y' in crange('a','z')
True
```

That means it takes about 0.35 seconds to search for character number 109,999 out of the maximum of 110,000. `109999 in range(110000)` is, of course, fast.

At that point, my first thought was to simply subclass range. Unfortunately:

```
>>> class A(range):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type 'range' is not an acceptable base type
```

So I guess I would have to mimic it in some way that allows me to pass characters as arguments, works like `range` internally, and produces characters. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried a `dir()`:

```
>>> print(*dir(range), sep='\n')
__class__
__contains__
__delattr__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__getitem__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__iter__
__le__
__len__
__lt__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__reversed__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
count
index
start
step
stop
```

which lets me see what functions are in there, but I'm not sure what they're doing, or how `range` uses them. I looked for the source for `range`, but it's in C, and I don't know where to find its Python wrapper (it does have one, right?).

Where do I go from here, and should I even go there?

Comment: "but it's in C, and I don't know where to find its Python wrapper (it does have one, right?)" - nope. Like `list` or `dict`, no part of `range` is written in Python.

Comment: About the class, perhaps `class A(object, range):`

Comment: While this might seem like an interesting question, I'm voting to close it as too broad. There's no good way to do this except by going through `range`'s entire API and replicating it, so answers would have to describe everything `range` does, all the hooks used to customize `len` and slicing and everything, and they'd take like 10 pages. I recommend googling the method names and looking through the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: alternative to existing version: `def crange(start, end): return map(chr, range(ord(start), ord(end)))`

Comment: I would have to disagree that it's too broad.  The OP already has a core method, what he needs to do is implement a lazy list, which is essentially how `range()` functions.  Once he has done that, he can work to implement the remainder of the range API and ask specific questions regarding them.  The OP may want to take a look at the [`lazyarray`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazyarray) module on PyPi to start with.  I would strongly suggest that the OP narrow his question down to lazy list implementation as quickly as possible to avoid being closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To add to Martin Konecny's answer. You probably want to use an internal range for everything and convert between chr and ord.

```
class crange:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        args = [ord(arg) for arg in args]
        kwargs = {key: ord(val) for key, val in kwargs.items()}
        self.range = range(*args, **kwargs)

    def __iter__(self):
        for n in self.range:
            yield chr(n)

    def __contains__(self, c):
        return ord(c) in self.range

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if isinstance(i, slice):
            ret = crange('\x00')
            ret.range = self.range[i]
            return ret
        else:
            return chr(self.range[i])

    def __repr__(self):
        return  "crange({}, {})".format(
            repr(chr(self.range.start)), repr(chr(self.range.stop)))

r = crange('a', 'f')
print(list(r))
print('b' in r)
print('f' in r)
print(r[:2])
```

In other words: if we can't subclass it we can use [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation).

Comment: I was about to ask if it would be a good idea to use a `range` object internally... :)

Comment: `self.range.__contains__(ord(c))` → `ord(c) in self.range`; `self.range.__getitem__(i)`→ `self.range[i]`, `('crange('+repr(chr(self.range.start))+', '+ repr(chr(self.range.stop))+')')` → `"crange({}, {})".format(self.range.start, self.range.stop)`.

Comment: Suggested changes made, thanks. Got myself stuck on using the method name for symmetry. repr was a mess, no excuse :(.

Answer (score 18):

> At that point, my first thought was to simply subclass range.

`range` was a function in Python2 and a "final" class in Python3 ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114382/276949)) - in both cases not something you can sub-class. You will need to create a class `crange` that extends from an `object` as the base type.

```
class crange(object):
```

> And this works, but is O(n), unlike range's O(1)

In Python 3, there is a [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) method that you will define for your object.

> For objects that don’t define `__contains__()`, the membership test first tries iteration via `__iter__()`, then the old sequence iteration protocol via `__getitem__()`, see this section in the language reference.

This allows Python to determine if the value is in your range without actually enumerating the range.

For a simple example, if your range is 1 to 1,000,000, it is trivial to determine whether 23546 is in that range (`1 < 23546 < 1000000`). Of course the actual implementation is a bit more complex and adds ability to handle step increments etc.

Regarding:

> Yay! But this doesn't work: `>>> crange('a','e')[::2]`

In this case you need to define `__getitem__` on your object. Here's an example of some of the methods required:

```
class crange(object):
    def __init__(self, start, end, step=1):
        # initialize your range object
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.step = step

    def __iter__(self):
        # enable iteration over your object
        # (assume step size is 1)
        for i in range(ord(self.start), ord(self.end)+1):
            yield chr(i)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        # enable accessing items in your range by index
        # also enable crange('a','e')[::2]
        # (assuming step size of 1)
        if isinstance( i, slice ):
            # implement slicing 
        else:
            return chr(ord(self.start) + i)

    def __contains__(self, char):
        # enable O(1) determination of whether a value is in your range
        # (assume step size is 1)
        return ord(self.start) <= ord(char) < ord(self.end)

    def __len__(self):
        # return length (assuming step size of 1)
        return ord(self.end) - ord(self.start)
```

Comment: If I remember, correctly, `__contains__()` is implemented in `range()` as: `if step == 1:  return start <= num < end` / `else: return start <= num < end and not (num - start) % step` (not sure why I know that).  The analogous function for `crange()` would be: `if step == 1: return ord(start) <= ord(c) < ord(end)` / `else: return ord(start) <= ord(c) < ord(end) and not (ord(c) - ord(start)) % step`.

Comment: @DougR.thx I filled in some of the methods, and used your `__contains__()` method

Comment: Glad to be of help.  Sorry it took me three times to get the whole thing right.  This is the kind of problem I like to see here on SO.

Comment: Your `__getitem__()` function appears to ignore the step.  I.e., if we did `my_crange = crange('a', 'm', 3)`, `my_crange[1] == 'd'`.  Your `__getitem__()` would return 'b'.  I think it should be `return chr(ord(self.start) + i * step)`

Comment: ...and I can't believe I made such a rookie mistake.  Looking back on my return value for `__contains__()`, no need to do an `if/else...`.  `n % 1 == 0` for any integer.

Comment: Minor quibble: `range` in Python 3 is a class, not a function, although that doesn't change the fact that it is unsubclassable.

Comment: @chepner - thx for the correction, found it's an immutable sequence type. It was a function in Python 2.

Comment: "range was a function in Python2 and an immutable sequence-type in Python3 - in both cases not something you can sub-class." - the fact that it can't be subclassed in Python 3 has nothing to do with the fact that it's an immutable sequence type. After all, you can subclass `tuple` just fine. You can't subclass `range` because it specifically disallows subclassing (by not setting the Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE flag).