# Python 3.5: subclasses of int don't call the __index__ method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused as to when the `__index__` method of a class is called. I had assumed the method would be called when ever the object was used in an indexing operation. I am not seeing `__index__` called when the object is a subclass of `int`.

```
In [1]: class foo(int):
...:        def __new__(cls, value):
...:            return int.__new__(cls, value)
...:        def __index__(self):
...:            return int(self)+1

In [2]: i=foo(0)

In [3]: i
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: i.__index__()
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: [0,1,2][:i.__index__()]
Out[5]: [0]

In [6]: [0,1,2][:i]
Out[6]: []
```

it appears that `int(i)` is being used as the index not `i.__index__()`. What have I misunderstood?

Edited to simplify and correct the example.

Comment: You have not misunderstood anything.

Comment: See the note in the [data model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__index__)

Comment: "

In order to have a coherent integer type class, when __index__() is defined __int__() should also be defined, and both should return the same value." seems that you have a problem now

Comment: Related: [Make an object that behaves like a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39971030/674039)

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Yes I do have a problem now, thanks all.

Comment: I think that's a XY problem... we don't know what you want to achieve globally

Comment: I'll just use another approach. It was mostly a learning exercise anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__index__` implements lossless conversion to `int`. Python only calls `__index__` if it actually needs such a conversion. In your case, it doesn't need a conversion, because your `i` is already an int. Python just uses the int value directly.

If you want to see the code that handles this, it's under [`PyNumber_Index`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.2/Objects/abstract.c#L1247).