# Use a variable to describe an index range/slice for array / list indexing

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, slice

I want to use a use a name to refer to an index range for array/list indexing.
Plus, I want to be able to do arithmetic on it.
For instance, I want to do

```
myrange = 3:10
myrange2 = myrange + 5
arr2[myrange2] = arr1[myrange]  # This being equivalent to arr2[8:15] = arr1[3:10] 
myrange3 = myrange * 2 + 5
arr2[myrange3] = arr1[myrange]  # This being equivalent to arr2[11:25] = arr1[3:10]
```

**Is this possible with python lists and numpy arrays?**

Comment: Looks difficult as slice is not subclassable https://stackoverflow.com/a/39971377/7207392. Also using dunders `__int__` or `__index__` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The 'm:n' slice notation only works in an indexing expression.  That is, it's a Python syntax feature.  The interpreter converts it to a `slilce` object, and passes that to the `__getitem__` method.  By itself a slice object is quite simple, with just a couple of attributes.  `np.s_` and `np.r_` are special `numpy` class instances that help generate and expand slices.

Comment: @hpaulj - I will try digesting your comment. In the meantime, would you say the answer to my question is Yes or No? (I could not figure this out from the comment, yet).

Comment: No, you cannot make the Python interpreter evaluate `myrange = 3:10`.  That's an `invalid syntax` error.

Comment: @hpaulj - Please see the approach in the answers... they seem to show that it is possible (by not using strictly the notation `3:10`, but being able to name a slice)...

Comment: Look at `numpy.lib.index_tricks.py` to see some games that `numpy` plays with slices.  It defines several classes that have their own `__getitem__` methods.  This allows them to use the `n:m:s` syntax.  One even allows a `complex` step value, `np.r_[0:10:11j]` is evaluated as `np.linspace(0,10,11)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a `slice()`:

```
myrange = slice(3, 10)
myrange2 = slice(3 + 5, 10 + 5)
arr2[myrange2] = arr1[myrange]
```

This can be made into a function easily:

```
def add_to_slice(slice_, offset):
    return slice(slice_.start + offset, slice_.stop + offset)


myrange = slice(3, 10)
myrange2 = add_to_slice(myrange, 5)
arr2[myrange2] = arr1[myrange]
```

If you want to use `+` you would need to patch the `slice` class (since `slice` is not an acceptable base class) to include a `__add__` method, i.e.:

```
class Slice(slice):
    pass
```

> TypeError: type 'slice' is not an acceptable base type

---

## EDIT

A "perhaps close enough" approach would be wrap a `slice` around another class, say `Slice` and, optionally, make it easy to access the inner `slice`, e.g.:

```
class Slice(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.slice_ = slice(*args)

    def __call__(self):
        return self.slice_

    def __add__(self, offset):
        return Slice(self.slice_.start + offset, self.slice_.stop + offset, self.slice_.step)


myrange = Slice(2, 5)
myrange2 = myrange + 3

mylist = list(range(100))
print(mylist[myrange()])
print(mylist[myrange2()])
```

(You may want to refine the code for production to handle the possibility of the attributes of `slice` being `None`).

Comment: Very interesting approach. I will try this out.
I meant to be able to do other arithmetic operations as well, and even compound operations (e.g., `slice * 2 + 4`). With this approach, it seems to me that is also straightforward, by defining `__multiply__`, etc. Would you think so?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica Yes, you can peek the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module to see what to implement (e.g. `*` operator is `__mul__`, etc.). Note that you could also accept a `str` in the constructor with the *colon* syntax, which would allow you to write `Slice('1:10')` in place of `Slice(1, 10)`, although that may be useful for handling user input than to simplify syntax in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice`

```
a = slice(1,3)
'hello'[a] -> ell
```

You can access the attributes with a.start/a.stop/a.step. The attributes are read only but you can create a new slice from them for the arithmetic requirement