# Extending the slice class

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I'm trying to create a class that behaves **exactly** as a slice, but that implements the `__add__` method to combine multiple slices in a single slice.

A simple mockup could be:

```
class cumslice(slice):
    def __add__(self, other):

        s1  = self.start
        e1  = self.end
        st1 = self.step

        s2  = other.start
        e2  = other.end
        st2 = other.step

        s = s1 + st1*s2
        st = st1*st2
        e = min([e1, s1 + st1*e2])

        return cumslice(s, e, st)
```

(note that we need some `if` to handles `None` values.)

However the code above returns

```
TypeError: type 'slice' is not an acceptable base type
```

Is it possible to do something like this without reimplementing the slice type from scratch?

Comment: `slice` is implemented as "final" and cannot be subclassed

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance if the latter is not possible.

Comment: @sanyash can you explain what this means?

Comment: do in your class the following: `self._slice = slice(start, stop, end)` and get `self._slice.start` instead of `self.start` when inheriting from `slice`.

Comment: @sanyash Doing this `x[cumslice(0,10,2)]` would raise the exception `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not cumslice`. I know I could do `x[cumslice(0,10,2)._slice]`, but this would require all the following code to be changed.

Comment: Ok, I realized that it is not as easy as it seemed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an object that behaves like a slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971030/make-an-object-that-behaves-like-a-slice)

Comment: @sanyash if the answer is “you can’t“, then unfortunately yes. It does answer