# Is it possible to mimic a python slice object or subclass?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, slice, subclassing

I would like to include some metadata into a python slice object, along with adding variables to indicate the index of each element in the slice. The metadata is used to label each element that the slice is retrieving. I know there are other labelled data structures that can be used, but in my project slices are predefined as a sort of subscript for numpy arrays and is re-used in various places. So, for me it makes sense to find a way to incorporate this.

I was thinking of sub-classing `slice`, but apparently it cannot be [subclassed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061752/which-classes-cannot-be-subclassed) which was explained clearly in the answer of the linked question. Has anything changed since then?

What I'd like to do is create a class that looks like:

```
class Subscript:
    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=None, labels=None):
        self.labels = labels
        self.slc = slice(start, stop, step)

        for i, l in zip(range(start, stop, step), labels):
            setattr(self, l, i)
```

and be able to use it like this:

```
sub = Subscript(0, 5, labels=['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4'])

list(range(10))[sub]  # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

range(10)[sub.s0]  # 0
```

is there a way to do this without having to add a `__call__` method to return the slice? Somehow I doubt this because the array or list taking in the `sub` through `__getitem__` wouldn't know what to do with this. I know that I could probably just monkey-patch this information to `slice`, but am wondering if this type of thing could be done in a class.

Currently, I am defining the slice and slice elements separately like:

```
sub = slice(0, 5)

s0, s1, s2, s3, s4 = range(5)
```

But this approach makes it much harder to process the output of multidimensional arrays into a dict where keys are subscript element combinations in the case of more than 1 `sub` and values are 1d arrays.

Comment: Please don't use `exec` to set the attributes dynamically, `setattr` is much better suited for this. Also, your `__init__` doesn't have `self`.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about that one

Answer (score 1):

Nope, `slice` objects still can't be sub-classed. I'm saying this based [on the flags](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3f29f4ad6ca29b1dcd9e551fcdba43d2f00dcd5/Objects/sliceobject.c#L620) defined for `PySlice_Type` in the default Python (`3.7`) branch:

```
Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC,    /* tp_flags */
```

To allow an object to act as a base class the appropriate [`Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE) would be `or`ed in there as they are with types defined allowed to. Taking [lists](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c3f29f4ad6ca29b1dcd9e551fcdba43d2f00dcd5/Objects/listobject.c#L2645) as an example, their flags are defined as:

```
Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_GC |
    Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE | Py_TPFLAGS_LIST_SUBCLASS,         /* tp_flags */
```

Ignoring the rest, `Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE` is `|`'ed in there allowing it to act as a base class.

Judging by the fact that I couldn't find this mentioned somewhere in the docs, I'd say it's an implementation detail whose rationale I'm currently not aware of. The only way I believe you *might* circumvent it is by dropping to `C` and making your class there.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like this is trickier than I thought. Even monkey-patching `slice` doesn't seem to be do-able because of this. I just get an `AttributeError` instead.

Comment: Yup @pbreach if I remember correctly, `list.__getitem__` (and the other containers should behave similarly) checks explicitly for a `slice` type as the argument passed to it or `int` values (at least, objects that provide an `__index__` method that returns an appropriate `int`). The best you'd likely be able to do is actually create a new `list` subtype that allows for custom objects that behave like `slice`s (by composition maybe?).

Comment: I ended up doing basically what you suggested except by subclassing `numpy.ndarray` instead of `list` and posted it here. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing is subclassed `numpy.ndarray` because I was only trying to pass the slices into this type of object (could do the same for list), and then reimplemented `__getitem__` so that if a `Subscript` object is passed in then the slice will first be extracted before passing onto the parent method.

Looks like:

```
import numpy as np

class SubArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, input_array, subs=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.subs = subs
        return obj

    def __getitem__(self, *args):
        args = tuple([a.slc if isinstance(a, SubRange) else a for a in args])
        return super().__getitem__(*args)

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        self.subs = getattr(obj, 'subs', None)


class Subscript:
    def __init__(self, labels, bounds=None):
        name, elements = labels

        if bounds:
            start, stop = bounds
        else:
            start, stop = 0, len(elements)

        self.size = stop - start
        self.slc = slice(start, stop)
        self.labels = labels
        self.name = name
        self.elements = elements

        for l, i in zip(labels, range(start, stop)):
            setattr(self, l, i)
```

And can use like this:

```
sub = Subscript(('sub', ['s0', 's1', 's2', 's3', 's4']))

SubArray(np.arange(10), subs=sub)[sub]  # SubArray([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

SubArray(np.arange(10), subs=sub)[sub.s0]  # 0
```

This is much closer to the approach that I was avoiding (i.e. using something like [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/)), but the result is still basically a numpy array and works for me.