# Python -- Class of functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def Func():
    pass
```

In an IPython session, when I enter type(Func) the output is "function". As Python is an object oriented language, I assume there is a class of which "Func" is an instance. So I tried creating my own class this way:

```
class MyFunc(function):
    pass
```

Alas, the interpreter just threw a "NameError" complaining that "function" is not defined.
So, I tried being a little clever and did this:

```
class myfunc(func.__class__):
    pass
```

Alas, it failed miserably...

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

In summary, could anyone explain:
1). How to create a class derived off of the type "function". If not possible, why?
2). What that error message really meant.

Comment: Thanks for this question- I never thought about doing this before

Comment: Python is a rabbit hole, innit?

Comment: But I think it's answered by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10114382/2958070. Specifically [this link](http://grokbase.com/t/python/python-list/033r5nks47/type-function-does-not-subtype#20030324rcnwbkfedhzbaf3vmiuer3z4xq)

Comment: FYI, the function type is actually available in `types.FunctionType`. You still can't inherit from it though.

Comment: if you want a signature of a function in your class, add a `__call__` method

Comment: Interesting, will check into that.

Comment: I have read the answer in the link you posted here. It was asked and answered by the same person. Is that a red flag?

Answer (score 1):

> In summary, could anyone explain: 1). How to create a class derived off of the type "function".

You can't.

> If not possible, why? 2). What that error message really meant.

That error message means that Python won't let classes use the function type as a base class. Classes implemented in C can only be extended if they set a specific flag; if they don't, this is the error you get when you try to extend them.