# Distinguish 0 from False when counting elements of a list

Tags: python, list, count, zero

Say I have an list of values that contains some `0`s and some `False`s.
Something like

```
arr = [0, False, False, 0, False]
```

How would I count each of them in Python?

`list.count` doesn't work here:

```
>>> arr.count(0)
5
>>> arr.count(False)
5
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? I suspect there might be a better way in the first place. For example, if you want to use placeholder elements in the list, it would be better to use `None` instead of `False`.

Comment: No particular problem.
THIS is what I was trying to figure.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use `is` to compare against `False`:

```
print(sum(1 for x in arr if x is False))
```

result: 3

(also works with `is 0` BTW)

EDIT: we could also rely on the fact that `True==1` after all: `sum(x is False for x in arr)` is even simpler.

Comment: I think that there's no guarantee to have a single `0` object - this _will probably_ work, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: This is surely the best way because `0` and `False` are singletons right?

Comment: well, there is also no guarantee that `False` is a singleton :-) It just so happens to be the case in CPython (and probably every other python implementation because it "makes sense").

Comment: This will be a lot slower than `list.count` though, would be nice if there was a `list.count` equivalent for identity (instead of equality)?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes. But who puts booleans _and_ integers in his lists? interesting problem, though.

Comment: @MSeifert [Guido says they are singletons](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2172189/216074). That’s as close as “per spec” as you can probably get :P

Comment: I wrote this answer with the classical pythonic `is None` in mind. `None` is also a singleton.

Comment: I've actually found a little simpler way to implement this: 
`sum(x is False for x in arr) ==> 3` and `sum(x is 0 for x in arr)` ==> 2`

Comment: Yeah, that's also why I included it (already) in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The only way to distinguish is by their type:

```
>>> type(False)
bool
>>> type(0)
int
```

But `isinstance` can't be used for `0` because `bool` is a subclass of `int`

```
>>> isinstance(0, bool)
False
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
```

And the values are just equal (that's why `count` doesn't work "correctly" for you):

```
>>> 0 == False
True
```

You could use the fact that `0` is an interned (singleton) integer in CPython  (probably also other Python implementations) and `False` is also a singleton:

```
>>> 0 is 0
True
>>> False is False
True
>>> 0 is False
False
```

---

As for a solution: Use something that isn't *so* equal, for example `None`:

```
arr = [0, None, None, 0, None]

arr.count(0)     # 2
arr.count(None)  # 3
```

If you really need to use `0` and `False` you could use `sum` (like others have shown):

```
sum(x is False for x in arr)  # for count(False)
sum(x is 0 for x in arr)      # for count(0)
```

Or Python-implementation independant: the `type` and value as identifier and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> arr = [0, False, False, 0, False]

>>> from collections import Counter

>>> Counter((type(x), x) for x in arr)
Counter({(bool, False): 3, (int, 0): 2})
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with using `isinstance` here? You could easily check if it’s *not* a bool?

Comment: It's no problem, but the logic is different: `if isinstance(x, bool)` (to count `False`) and `if **not** isinstance(x, bool)` (to count `0`). That doesn't generalize "well".

Comment: `not isinstance(x, bool) and x == 0`?

Comment: @poke I meant the `not` differs between both approaches, that makes it asymmetric. I wanted to show rather general approaches that work if instances are equal but their classes differ. The `sum(x is 0 for x in arr)` and `sum(x is False for x in arr)` are not general but at least symmetric. For example it get's really complicated when it contains floats `0.0`, ints `0` and bools `False`. :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a rare case where it seems sensible to just use a type check.

```
sum(1 for item in arr if item == 0 and type(item) is type(0))
```

As mentioned by Jean-François, if you're guaranteed to only have 0 and `False`, the type check is sufficient on its own.

Comment: and if there are only 0 and `False` values, the type check is enough.

Comment: you're talking to the upvoter here so I wouldn't know :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh man did that ping you? If so my apologies lol :P

Comment: no problem at all! Since downvoter is not an user (it could be :)) the last commenter is pinged. I'd like to know why you got a downvote too...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `defaultdict` on order to find the count of both 0 and False at once:

```
In [73]: from collections import defaultdict

In [74]: d = defaultdict(int)

In [75]: for i in arr:
   ....:     d[str(i)] += i is False or 1 # if I is not False is 0
   ....:     

In [76]: d
Out[76]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'0': 2, 'False': 3})
```